# How to get the MvxGridView to be efficient and performant?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

Using Xamarin and MvvmCross, I'm writing an Android application that is loading the images from an album into an **MvxGridView** with a custom binding:

```
 <MvxGridView
    android:id="@+id/grid_Photos"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:verticalSpacing="4dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="4dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource AllPhotos"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_photo_thumbnail" />
```

Which uses **item_photo_thumbnail.axml**:

```
<ImageView
    local:MvxBind="PicturePath PhotoPath"
    style="@style/ImageView_Thumbnail" />
```

Here is the binding class:

```
public class PicturePathBinding : MvxTargetBinding
{
    private readonly ImageView _imageView;

    public PicturePathBinding(ImageView imageView)
        : base(imageView)
    {
        _imageView = imageView;
    }

    public override MvxBindingMode DefaultMode
    {
        get { return MvxBindingMode.OneWay; }
    }

    public override Type TargetType
    {
        get { return typeof(string); }
    }

    public override void SetValue(object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        string path = value as string;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
        {
            Java.IO.File imgFile = new Java.IO.File(path);

            if (imgFile.Exists())
            {
                // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.InJustDecodeBounds = true;
                BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(imgFile.AbsolutePath, options);

                // Calculate inSampleSize
                options.InSampleSize = CalculateInSampleSize(options, 100, 100);

                // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
                options.InJustDecodeBounds = false;
                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(imgFile.AbsolutePath, options);
                _imageView.SetImageBitmap(myBitmap);
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool isDisposing)
    {
        if (isDisposing)
        {
            var target = Target as ImageView;
            if (target != null)
            {
                target.Dispose();
                target = null;
            }
        }
        base.Dispose(isDisposing);
    }

    private int CalculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight)
    {
        // Raw height and width of image
        int height = options.OutHeight;
        int width = options.OutWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth)
        {
            int halfHeight = height / 2;
            int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight &&
                    (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth)
            {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that it is very sluggish and slow. I would love for the each image to load asynchronously. I don't know how to do that. In .net (XAML), their GridView control does everything automatically (with virtualization), but I'm realizing that in Android, it might have to be manually handled?

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Consider adding the Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.DownloadCache, and Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.File MvvmCross plugins to your project.  This should improve performance by automatically caching the images and reusing them.

Comment: Wow, I never tried that. Once I add them, is there anything else I need to do for the caching to be in effect?

Comment: If you add the libraries via NuGet then no additional steps are required.  The MvvmCross plugins are supposed to be registered, and this should happen automatically if using NuGet.  There is documentation available here: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/MvvmCross-plugins

Answer (score 2):

I am currently working with remote images, instead of local, so I have been using the Download Cache plugin that gives you the MvxImageView class.  That in itself may give you some benefit.

So far my experience with Android is that everything runs if foreground by default, for the most part. Right now, with all of the calculation code inside of the binding class, that is almost certainly going to be run in the foreground.

What I would do to make this run faster is:

- Use something like an ObservableCollection for your ItemsSource.
- Kick off another thread in the start (or Start) of your View Model to add your items to the ObservableCollection.  You can accomplish this easily with Task.Run()
- Try to process as much as possible in that background thread with each item before adding it to the ObservableCollection
- When updating ObservableCollection from the background thread, the actual update itself has to be done on the UI thread.  This is easily done if you are using MvxViewModel as your base for your view model.

  this.InvokeOnMainThread(() => myObservableCollection.Add(myItem) );

Following that pattern should actually help you Windows based clients as well.

Comment: Thanks!! I'll give this a shot as well as trying the download cache plugin. I'll report back one I do so :)

Comment: Ok, I see a problem with this. If you look at the above code, specifically the code related to the decoding of the byte array (BitmapFactory), I cannot have that code within a ViewModel since it is Android specific. I don't think I can have that code in a Binding or Converter and let it run asynchronously in a Task. Am I right to assume that?